# git squash in-place upstream of a merge

Tags: git

I want to know how to squash some commits that are upstream of a merge.  Below is an attempt at doing this, which resulted in the newly squashed branch becoming independent, while leaving the original commits un-merged.

```
$ git checkout dev-track_rpm
Switched to branch 'dev-track_rpm'
$ git lg
**removed a bunch of log for brevity**
| * 6802588 - (2 months ago)
* | 267b937 - (1 month ago)
|/
*   45f7846 - (2 months ago) Merge branch 'dev-track_rpm'
|\
| * 7e07b43 - (2 months ago) (HEAD, dev-track_rpm)
| * 5cce85b - (2 months ago)
| * e36f2fb - (2 months ago)
| * 081175b - (2 months ago)
* | 4896e1f - (2 months ago)
|/
* 4767c9d - (2 months ago)


$ git rebase -i -p 4767c9d **also tried without -p initially**
*choose to squash 5cce85b and e36f2fb**
[detached HEAD c77cf3e]
 20 files changed, 4139 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
**removed file list for brevity**
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/dev-track_rpm.
$ git lg
* 260cdce - (2 months ago) (HEAD, dev-track_rpm)
* c77cf3e - (2 months ago)
**removed same bunch of log for brevity**
| | * 6802588 - (2 months ago)
| * | 267b937 - (1 month ago)
| |/
| *   45f7846 - (2 months ago) Merge branch 'dev-track_rpm'
| |\
| | * 7e07b43 - (2 months ago)
| | * 5cce85b - (2 months ago)
| | * e36f2fb - (2 months ago)
| | * 081175b - (2 months ago)
| |/
|/|
| * 4896e1f - (2 months ago)
|/
* 4767c9d - (2 months ago)
$
```

I wanted to get this:

```
$ git lg
**removed a bunch of log for brevity**
| * 6802588 - (2 months ago)
* | 267b937 - (1 month ago)
|/
*   45f7846 - (2 months ago) Merge branch 'dev-track_rpm'
|\
| * <some new sha> - (2 months ago) same changes as 7e07b43 (HEAD, dev-track_rpm)
| * <some new sha> - (2 months ago) squashed 
* | 4896e1f - (2 months ago)
|/
* 4767c9d - (2 months ago)
```

Comment: That's right.  Nothing in the object db ever changes, you add new things to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a rebase you change the hash order of the tree, so it will appear as a different tree no matter what you do, the only solution would be force push the new tree to replace the old tree, though there's usually discouraged, especially when this is a shared project where you have multiple committers.

**EDIT**:
Here's a simple explanation of what you want to do:

Assume this current tree ( Assume these letters are commit hashes )

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

And you want to squash `B` and `C` and `D`

So you run this command

```
git rebase -i B~
```

Mind that `B~` is also the same as `A`, you want the parent of the last commit you want to edit, I usually use the `~` format.

you'll get your editor with these lines

```
pick B the b message
pick C the c messasge
pick D the d message
pick E the e message
```

you will change the picks into squahses

```
pick B the b message
squash C the c messasge
squash D the d message
pick E the e message
```

The rebase will start to pick the commits, then it will stop again and show you the log of the two commits you are squashing, and asks you to pick one or edit both and write a new message, just save and the tree will continue to be rebased.

Now you will end up with a tree looking like this

```
A -> BCD' -> E'
```

Notice that even though you only edited the `B`,`C`, and `D` commits , `E` also got changed, because the tree below it got changed, if you draw the whole tree it would look like this

```
A -> BCD' -> E' <- HEAD and BRANCH will be here
 \-> B -> C -> D -> E ( this part will be detached )
```

You will then push the HEAD or BRANCH to the origin with forced `-f`

```
git push origin BRANCH -f
```

Comment: I'm the only one using this repo.  I could force push the tree, but i'm still going to end up with the tree i got right, just now it's pushed.   Can you explain how that's a solution?

Comment: I don't really understand which commits you want to merge/squash, can you explain in simpler method the current tree and desired tree

Comment: I want to squash 5cce85b and e36f2fb into 081175b